# Vue 2 not updating specific component properties despite v-if v-else directive, while the rest is updated successfully

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue2 is not updating one specific component (`<Button>`) inside `v-if` and `v-else`, while the rest of the content is updated.

I have just found out a way to make this code work, but I do not catch the behaviour of Vue2 re-rendering, and I am afraid that I will not be able to make it work this way anytime, because here I only have 2 conditionally excludent blocks (or `<v-if>` and `v-else`, and now I use `<span>` and `<div>` for each).

**This was the original code that does not work**. The problem is that it did not update the  component once the condition ('root.authentication') is changed, but seamlessly, the `<p>` tag is updated successfully (why `<Button>` not?):

```
<template>
    <span v-if="root.authentication" data-id-logout-box>
      <p>Logout</p>
      <Button :root="root" text-label-preset="Salir" :on-click-preset="root.logout" />
    </span>
    <span v-else data-id-login-box>
      <p>Login</p>
      <Button :root="root" text-label-preset="Entrar" :on-click-preset="root.login" />
    </span>
</template>
```

**This second code does the trick.** The only difference is that, in the previous, there were 2 span tags, while in this one, there is 1 span and 1 div tag:

```
<template>
    <span v-if="root.authentication" data-id-logout-box>
      <Button :root="root" text-label-preset="Salir" :on-click-preset="root.logout" />
    </span>
    <div v-else data-id-login-box>
      <Button :root="root" text-label-preset="Entrar" :on-click-preset="root.login" />
    </div>
</template>
```

I have tried to do it changing the class attribute applied to that elements, and also playing with `data-*` attributes, as you can see in the example. But none of them worked.

My quesiton is, as I do not have infinite tags to make it work, how could I do the workaround for this, in order to make it work with infinite nested `<v-else-if>`?

Thank you.

Comment: There could be a problem with the single closing tag: <Button />, you could replace it with <Button ... ></Button>. There could also be a problem with the Button component, it has the same name as the native html button component. You could try to rename Button to MyButton.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a CSS problem? span is `display: inline;` by default, while div tags are `display: block;` by default. Have you checked using [Vue Development tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg)?

Comment: Hey Joshua, I have tried that naming it SimpleButton instead, but the behaviour remains.

Comment: Hey Joshua and Peter, I am almost sure it has something to do with the way Vue2 does the dirty checking, and as the tag element cannot be modified (while a class or a `data-*` attributes could), it re-renders the content. I have tried different methods, and it seems to update it if both components (SimpleButton) do not have the same hierarchy, for example, despite being the same tag.

Comment: Hey Peter, it seems to work well if I change the tags by `<p>` also, with `<div>` or `<span>`, so I don't think it is the CSS rule, I am sure it is something related with the dirty-checking algorythm of Vue. That is why I ask if there is any workaround or something for infinite conditions, as I got working with 2 conditions at least, but I don't know what to do if I had 20 conditions. At least, I got it working with this dirty workaround.

Comment: Try giving different keys to both button it may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If and else elements are identical that's causing this issue. when you are changing else part to div fixes because how vue update and render template.
for more details
https://snipcart.com/blog/vue-render-functions

you can give first span and second span unique keys and that should solve the problem.

Comment: V-BIND:KEY. I did not think about it as solution. Boss, thank you! ;)